# What is Mandalorian armor made of?

Tags: star-wars, armor, mandalorian

What is Mandalorian armor made of?  Do we even know?

I have watched every "Clone Wars" and "Rebels" Episode like twice or more and I can't remember if it ever says anything like that.

Is there maybe a book that says?

Answer (score 9):

### [Beskar](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beskar)

> Beskar, also known as Mandalorian iron, was an alloy used in Mandalorian armor, notable for its high tolerance to extreme forms of damage. The metal was durable enough to withstand a direct blaster shot, and could potentially withstand the slash or glancing blow of a lightsaber, though could be penetrated with a direct stab.

Comment: I do not think this is cannon anymore, extendedv universe and all

Comment: @GarretGang Beskar is in Disney canon. It has been described in some episodes of "Rebels", and IIRC in the recent "Thrawn" books there is a secret base discovered that is mining it for the Empire

Comment: Good to know. They are at least stealing a little from "Legends"

Comment: Also canon from the series The Mandalorian now.